# Printing diagram of an AVL Tree in Java

Tags: java, tree, diagram, avl-tree

I need to print a diagram of an AVL tree in java, the only requirements are I need to use an iterator and cannot use arraylist...arbitrary aspect from my prof. Because it is AVL, I can't seem to find a logical way around getting rid of a NoSuchElementException when there is a hole in the tree. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this your homework? If yes, please include the tag.

Comment: and the problem is ? as a side not look like a good task though.

Comment: Why write special code to print an AVL tree?  Write code to print a arbitrary binary tree and [it will just work for AVL trees](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/05/your-favorite-programming-quote.html). Or maybe this is homework and you are being forced to shove a display method inside the AVL tree class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing binary tree to standard output Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945037/printing-binary-tree-to-standard-output-java)